# Why 0 is being appended at the end for the values taken from cics

Tags: db2, cobol, cics

I have a numeric field in a cics map and is of length 3. When i enter 10 in the field and try to insert to a database by storing into a working storage variable in cobol program, It is being inserted as 100. Why is this happening so? Is there any way to insert it in the beginning

Comment: See my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10387657/192510). Notice that a SPACE from a PIC X field translates to a zero when moved to a PIC 9 field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default for a BMP field is left justification with blank padding.

You need to add JUSTIFY=(RIGHT,ZERO) to your DFHMDF field definition.

Here's the [CICS Application Programming Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/txformp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.te.doc/erziah0034.htm).